# Не устанавливается Node.js под Kali Linux

Tags: linux, node.js

При попытке установки `Node.js` в Kali Linux получаю ошибку:

```
make[1]: *** [/tmp/tmp.SIsSiBidmH/node-v8.6.0/out/Release/obj.host/
  genccode/deps/icu-small/source/tools/genccode/genccode.o] Ошибка 1
make[1]: *** Ожидание завершения заданий…
rm ea3e6c32ad2570e6011497ba319f129ea559cb61.intermediate
Makefile:76: ошибка выполнения рецепта для цели «node»
make: *** [node] Ошибка 2

****  Установка неудачна. Отменяется создание пакета.

Очищается...OK

Удачи.
```

Использовала этот [ресурс](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/410/how-to-install-node-js-in-kali-linux)

В чём прочина ошибки?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/ `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -`
`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

Comment: а с оффсайта скачать ноду в архиве и просто распаковать, не?

Comment: Большое спасибо! первый способ сработал.